# Matlab 30 Khz still be heard

Tags: matlab, audio, signals

By using the Matlab code as below, I created 30 Khz signal and used sound function to hear the signal created. But, according to my knowledge, I, as a human, should not have heard anything above 20Khz. What is the part that i am missing below? Am I not a human?

```
clear
Fs = 96000;
toneFreq1 = 30000;   
nSeconds = 2;
f1 = 10*cos( linspace (0, nSeconds*toneFreq1*2*pi, round(nSeconds*Fs) ) );
freqz( f1, length(f1) )
sound(f1, Fs);
```

Comment: With great power comes great responsibility!

Comment: An answer would be more helpful for the first rather than the second:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems I was wrong assuming the cause was only aliasing. In fact when you look at the source code of `sound`, you will find in line `52`:

```
% Make sure y is in the range +/- 1
y = max(-1,min(y,1));
```

Which will just cut off the signal above 1 and below -1. It seems your input values to `sound` should be in the interval `[-1,1]`, even though it is not explicitly mentioned in the documentation. If you don't pass in a signal with values in this range *clipping* will occur. The mixture of clipping and aliasing caused by the sampling will produce these frequencies below 20khz, that you are hearing.
So to make your code work just remove the `10*`.

**Old part - The problem is not only caused by aliasing, so the following is insufficient:**

What you are hearing is [aliasing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aliasing):
Just plot the first few values of your signal

```
plot(f1(1:50))
```

You would want this to look like a sine wave. Well, it doesn't.

[image: Not a sine]

Comment: But Nyquist rate criterion is satisfied, isnt it? So why aliasing occurs in this?

Comment: The sampling rate must be at least double the frequency to be *theoretically* able to *filter out the original signal*. It doesn't mean that every implementation of a sound-output will actually try to fit sine frequencies. I'm not sure what MATLAB `sound` actually does, but aliasing is certainly the culprit.

Comment: I think aliasing still occur but with the better sine wave. Plot of the f1 is not still a proper sine wave I guess. If I remove 10* , I even could not hear 19 Khz. Because It is too silent. What my intention by multiplication is that I wanted to hear, if there is some noise. But, now, I am sure that It is something with the sound function:)

Comment: You're definitely hearing some high-order harmonic that gets aliased into the audible spectrum. Harmonics are a result of the clipping caused by `sound`. Try plotting a clipped version of `f1` with `freqz( min(max(f1,-1),1), length(f1) )`, and you'll see all those harmonics. The "fundamental" is at 6000 kHz. Compare what you hear with `sound(.5*sin(2*pi*6e3*(0:1/Fs:1)), Fs);`. You'll find is the same "musical note"

Comment: @LuisMendo: Yup, it is definitely aliasing (caused by clipping), I just initially thought it was due to insufficient sampling and a possibly odd implementation of `sound`, as I could get rid of the harmonic using an integer multiple of the frequency as a sampling rate. Turns out this - even though it certainly works due to `lcm==Fs` - is obviously overkill, since `sound` isn't broken, only not perfectly documented.

Comment: One thing is clipping, which causes harmonics, and a different thing is sampling, which causes aliasing. The aliasing is not _caused_ by the clipping. Aliasing is produced by the sampled nature of the waveform, and causes high-order harmonics to appear in the audible spectrum

Comment: @LuisMendo: But without the clipping problem, no sound is output. As it is my understanding, using double the sampling rate of the signal will theoretically make you able to reconstruct the signal (as it is square integrable with limited frequency spectrum), filtering the harmonics, which MATLAB seemingly accomplishes.

Comment: Without clipping there are no harmonics, and the signal is not audible. With clipping there are many harmonics, some of which don't satisfy the Nyquist criterion (double sampling rate). Those get aliased and fall into the audible band

Comment: @LuisMendo: I guess we agree, but may differ on the wording, that in the end the audible frequencies (what I called aliasing) are caused by the clipping. Even though I disagree on the *without clipping there are no harmonics* part, as the unfiltered linearly interpolated signal definitely will have those, even without clipping (visible in the plot), but will get processed away by `sound`.

Comment: @knedlsepp Yes, we are probably saying the same just with different words :-) But notice that clipping alone wouln't generate audible frequencies. It would just generate harmonics at frequencies 2*toneFreq1, 3*toneFreq1 etc, which are not audible. You also need the second part: aliasing, which "folds" the spectrum so that those harmonics get aliased below 20 kHz. For example, the fifth harmonic has frequency 30e3*5. It gets aliased into 30e3*5-48000*3, or 6000 Hz, and so is audible

Comment: @LuisMendo: To settle the confusion: We agree that the cause for this is clipping+aliasing-by-sampling. I was simply assuming sampling as inherently part of the process, as it has to be for continuous signals generated by discrete samples. So: *But notice that clipping alone wouln't generate audible frequencies.* is certainly true for purely analog audio processing, but as we're dealing with digital to analog conversion, aliasing is there naturally and causes the trouble.

Comment: @LuisMendo: I see what started the confusion: I didn't know *harmonics* were the integer multiples of the signals frequency; I thought this was referring to the frequencies that sneak in by the greatest common divisor of sampling rate and frequency! :-)

Comment: @knedlsepp Settled, then! :-)